# integer arrays(eg: int a[]) in c: Why are wrong values being returned when I access them using a[i].?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    int a[100];
    int j;

    printf("enter nos");
    gets(a);

    for(j=0;j<strlen(a);j++){  
        printf("\n %d",a[j]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

for i/p nos: 1 2 3
the output is : 3355185 
                4915512
                1995911159

Whats going on ?

This is the main(full) program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j,k,seq=0,m=2,q=2,l;int n;
    int a[10];int s[10];                   //I tried using char but later in the for loop I have to compare j(int) and n. n gets its value from array. So implicit conversion messes it up.
    printf("\n enter the array elts ");
    gets(a);
    puts(a);
    printf("\n enter the  sequence ");
    gets(s) ;
    puts(s);

    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {
        n=(s[i]-1); printf("\n %d",s[i]); //I know that the problem is due to some implicit     conversion from char to int.
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)                    //But I don't know how to fix it
        {
            seq=seq+m;
        }
        printf("\n %d",seq);
        for(k=0,l=(seq);k<q;k++,l++)
        {
            putchar(a[l]);} m=2;seq=0;
        }
        getch();
    }
```

I'm trying to   Get the elements in the array,  divide the array into partitions of length m and  display the partitions in the user given sequence

Input :
Array elements : 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90
Order M : 2
(partitions 10, 20 | 30, 40 | 50, 60 | 70, 80 | 90)
Sequence order :
5, 2, 4, 1, 3
Output : 
90,30,40,70,80,10,20,50,60

EDIT: Can't believe this worked I subtracted 48 from n. I found out that when n is 2, somehow the for loop executed 50 times.I have no Idea what I did. Can someone explain it to me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j,k,seq=0,m=2,q=2,l;char n;
    char a[10];char s[10];
    printf("\n enter the array elts ");
    gets(a);
    puts(a);
    printf("\n enter the  sequence ");
    gets(s) ;
    puts(s);

    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {
        n=(s[i]-1);
        for(j=0;j<n-48;j++)
        {
            seq=seq+m;
        }
        for(k=0,l=(seq);k<q;k++,l++)
        {
            putchar(a[l]);} m=2;seq=0;
        }
        printf("\n");
        getch();
    }
```

Comment: Did your compiler warn you not to use `gets`, did it?

Comment: Have you thought about reading a manual? Or do you chuck your lunch into a machine and hope for the best after pressing a couple of buttons.

Comment: While rtfm is good advice and I bet the OP didn't bother I must admit that "gets() reads a line from stdin into the buffer pointed to by s" (from http://linux.die.net/man/3/gets) can be misinterpreted by an absolute beginner. It's the only information the page gives about what `gets` does. So, OP: `gets` just puts the characters you enter into the memory pointed to by the argument, one after the other; it does not interpret them in any way, so no integers are created. Use `scanf()` for that, and read a tutorial about it. There are plenty.

Comment: Always compile your programs with all warnings enabled, and handle them *before you ask for help*. Use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: @Deduplicator those options are not supported on every compiler; your answer should specify which compiler you mean as they may not apply to the one the OP is using. (Normally my replies are without my own -pedantic flag turned on, but in this case... :)

Comment: @Nick: Well, your nitpick is right, but all compilers not supporting one of those flags will at least ignore them with a warning, *which OP should be able to handle*.

Comment: @duplicator Possibly, or the compile might even fail entirely, but if there was a -p option that took characters after it then it might be silent. To be fair, assuming he has a gcc derivative is probably safe, but it's not a given, that's all :)

Comment: Please format your code. It's just plain unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//store a string to an array that contains the numbers separated by spaces
//return the number that can be read
int intoArray(char line[], int a[], size_t size);

int main(){
    char line[1024];
    int a[16], s[16], m;
    int alen, slen;
    int i, j;

    printf("\nenter the array : ");
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    alen = intoArray(line, a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a));

    printf("\nenter the sequence : ");
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    slen = intoArray(line, s, sizeof(s)/sizeof(*s));

    printf("\nenter length of partitions : ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    for(i = 0; i < slen ; ++i){
        for(j = m*(s[i]-1); j < alen && j < m*s[i] ; ++j){
            printf("%d ", a[j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int intoArray(char line[], int a[], size_t size){
    const char *delimiter = " \t\n";
    char *p = line;
    size_t i = 0;
    for(p = strtok(p, delimiter); p && i < size; p = strtok(NULL, delimiter)){
        int num;
        if(1==sscanf(p, "%d", &num))
            a[i++] = num;
    }
    return i;
}
/* demo
enter the array : 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90

enter the sequence : 5 2 4 1 3

enter length of partitions : 2
90 30 40 70 80 10 20 50 60
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

`gets` (an evil function) expects a pointer to `char`. You are passing a pointer to `int`. This is a constraint violation. Use `fgets` instead and declare `a` as `char` array.

```
char a[100];   
fgets(a, 100, stdin);
```

Comment: you can do this `char a[ 100 ];` and `printf( "%c\n", a[ j ] );`

Comment: Ufff! A comment would be appreciated.

Comment: Which is meant to accomplish what exactly? I think the OP wants to fill an int array with ints, e.g. parse the input. (I didn't downvote, in case you care.)

Comment: @PeterSchneider; Did OP told you/downvoter about that ?

Comment: Yes. He wrote "int a[100]", and then "Enter numbers".

Comment: @PeterSchneider; He is using `gets` and `strlen` too.

Comment: True. he is confused.

Comment: You picked out one small error, which is obviously not the main trouble the OP has, and only handle that? No wonder someone downvoted you.

Comment: I need to compare the value of the array with j which is an integer. So The array element should be an integer inorder to avoid distorted values due to implicit conversion that C does.

Comment: @Deduplicator; *You picked out one small error*: I do not think any error is small specially in context of programming.

Comment: @haacks: In comparison to what's needed for a good answer, yes, that error is small (It is a consequent error, i.e. it follows from the actual problem the OP has). That has nothing to do with that error alone being enough to break the program.

Comment: @Deduplicator; You could post your own answer.